# Find the values added or deleted in a list between the most recent date and past month

Tags: excel, vba, compare

For each group in column B, I want to identify the values in column A that were added on the most recent date or deleted from the previous month.

[image]

Result :

[image]

I managed to do it on a simplified example but not on the above format where the data are stored one below the other by fields.

[image]

```
Sub CompareSheetsV2()

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wsB As Worksheet
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Dim cellA As Range
Dim cellB As Range
Dim found As Range

Set wsA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("a")
Set rngA = wsA.Range("A2:A" & wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Set rngB = wsA.Range("B2:B" & wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cellA In rngA
    Set found = rngB.Find(cellA.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If found Is Nothing Then
        cellA.Offset(0, 5).Value = cellA.Value
        cellA.Offset(0, 6).Value = "deleted"
    Else

    End If
Next cellA


For Each cellB In rngB

    Set found = rngA.Find(cellB.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If found Is Nothing Then
        wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = cellB.Value
        wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "added"
    Else

    End If
Next cellB
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "list format" of your data? Sorry, it is unclear to me what is the actual format of your data (table at the beginning or at the end of your question).

Comment: It is the table at the beginning that interests me and that I can't solve. I do not succeed in defining the ranges which satisfy the two conditions to carry out the research there. (same group : "a", and same "date") ?

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the code (which I tried to make self-documenting) and the comments closely and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

*Note: Not sure of what I show is suitable for your output, but that is easily altered -- eg Transpose in PQ if you want rows*

**M Code**

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table19"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}, {"Group", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),

//Group by "Group"
/* Most Recent Month = latest month in subgroup
   Previous month = month prior to Most Recent Month*/
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group"}, {
        {"added/deleted", (t)=>
            let 
                #"Most Recent Date" = List.Max(t[Date]),
                #"Most Recent Month Start" = Date.StartOfMonth(#"Most Recent Date"),
                #"Previous Month Start" = Date.AddMonths(#"Most Recent Month Start",-1),
                #"Countries in Previous Month" = Table.SelectRows(t, each [Date] >= #"Previous Month Start" and [Date] < #"Most Recent Month Start")[Country],
                #"Countries in Most Recent Month" =  Table.SelectRows(t, each [Date] >= #"Most Recent Month Start")[Country],
                added = List.RemoveMatchingItems(#"Countries in Most Recent Month",#"Countries in Previous Month"),
                deleted = List.RemoveMatchingItems(#"Countries in Previous Month",#"Countries in Most Recent Month")
            in 
                Table.FromColumns(
                    {added,deleted},
                    {
                        "Added","Deleted"
                    })
                
        }}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Group"}),
    #"Expanded added/deleted" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "added/deleted", {"Added", "Deleted"}),

//Delete nulls from each column
    #"Delete Nulls" = Table.FromColumns(
        {List.RemoveNulls(#"Expanded added/deleted"[Added]),
        List.RemoveNulls(#"Expanded added/deleted"[Deleted])},
        type table[Added=text, Deleted=text])
 in 
    #"Delete Nulls"
```

[image]

***After Transposing in PQ***
[image]

Comment: Can simplify code after certain of exactly what you want for output.